# "Непонятно" и "не понятно": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно написать: "непонятно" или "не понятно" в предложении?

> Если вам (не)понятно, не обращайтесь сразу же за разьяснениями к старшим, а загляните в словарь.

Answer (score 7):

Написание предикативных наречий на -О с НЕ  зависит от понимания смысла фразы пишущим. При утверждении они пишутся слитно,при отрицании раздельно.
Мне видится здесь отрицание:Если вам не понятно(отрицается, что понятно), не обращайтесь...Одному понятно, другому не понятно.

Слитно было бы в таком примере:Непонятно (странно), почему они не пришли.

Но это моё субъективное мнение, у Вас может быть другое видение,пишите так, как Вы понимаете смысл.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то, в данном предложении НЕ должно писаться слитно, так как нет противопоставления и слово "непонятно" можно заменить синонимом. Однако Розенталь допускает и случаи, когда слитное или раздельное написание частицы НЕ зависит от смысла фразы. При отрицании пишется раздельно, при утверждении - слитно.

Answer (score 3):

> Если вам (не)понятно, не обращайтесь сразу же за разьяснениями к старшим, а загляните в словарь.

Поставим сказуемое в прошедшее время и сразу появляется глагол-связка *быть*.

> Если вам *было* непонятно...

Это говорит о том, что **непонятно** - это часть составного именного сказуемого, с опущенной грамматической связкой **быть**.
Так как именная часть сказуемого выражена наречием, то для образования формы прошедшего времени появляется глагол-связка *быть* (являться), что указывает, что **непонятно** это составное именное сказуемое, именная часть которого выражена наречием.
Даже если сказуемое состоит из одного слова – имени или наречия (с нулевой связкой), это всегда составное именное сказуемое.
**Непонятно** это не предикатив, а именная часть составного именного сказуемого выраженная наречием, поэтому с не пишется слитно по правилам наречия, а не раздельно, как предикатив с функцией глагола.

Comment: «Сказуемое в прошедшее время» зачем? Вполне подходят: будет, станет.

Comment: Пардон, недописал.
Чтобы проявился глагол-связка быть, отвечающий за категорию времени сказуемого, именная часть которого время не выражает.
Вы предлагаете тот же фокус в другую сторону.

Comment: Или вы предлагаете использовать для проявления глагола-связки категорию вида, так же присущую только глаголу?