# "Ну и заголовок, ничего непонятно..." — НЕ слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Есть предложение:

> Ну и заголовок, ничего непонятно...

Нужно ли здесь ставить пробел в слове "непонятно"?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vIMl.png

Comment: Это не дубликат вопроса, и я голосую за переоткрытие. В данном случае речь идет об усилительной конструкции "ничего непонятно" с одним вариантом написания, а в предыдущем вопросе обсуждалось написание "непонятно или не понятно" без усилительного значения (там два варианта). Вопрос важный, принципиальный. Речевой оборот "ничего не понятно" используется часто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. У Грамоты все **однозначно:**

**№299997**

Ничего непонятно или ничего не понятно – как правильно писать, если дано только словосочетание, без контекста?

**ОТВЕТ**

2. Верно: ***ничего не понятно***.

Надо думать, что здесь **усиление** отрицания. Почему делают ошибки? Думаю, по аналогии с утвердительным предложением: ***Все непонятно.***

Comment: Ну и заголовок - и есть контекст

Comment: Здесь дело не в контексте,  Грамота дает ответ для любого варианта: написание всегда раздельное (ничего не понятно). Это отрицательная конструкция (с усилением отрицания).  В утвердительном варианте  теряется смысл сказанного: непонятен некий предмет, который мы обозначили как "ничего",

Comment: *если дано только словосочетание, без контекста?* =>здесь вопрос поставлен неккоректно, тк есть контекст, поэтому это ответ от грамоты не подходит под данный вопрос, тк повторюсь контекст имеется !!! //"ничего не понятно" - это устойчивое выражение, которое следует писать слитно. Таким образом, правильно будет: "Ну и заголовок, ничего непонятно..."

Comment: Какие у вас источники, где это указано? Например, что это устойчивое выражение?  Без ссылок нельзя что-либо утверждать. Обычно такая информация легко находится.  На Грамоте ничего нет по теме, кроме одного ответа..  В Сети считают, что НЕ  пишется раздельно. https://posostavu.ru/44479-pnichego-neponyatno-ili-nichego-ne-ponyatno-kak-pravilno-pisat-9025.html    https://otvet.mail.ru/question/173594814

Comment: какие у вас источники? ссылка ваша указывает *если дано только словосочетание, без контекста?* контекст есть, и это *Ну и заголовок*

Comment: Разговор сейчас о вас: есть ли у вас ссылки?  Мое решение.  Ищу на Грамоте по всем разделам. Ничего нет, кроме одного сообщения.  Набираю устойчивое выражение, тоже нет такого. Пользователи выбирают раздельное написание. Дальше решаю сама: это стандартная отрицательная конструкция (усиление отрицания), нет причин в этом сомневаться.  А вам придется доказать, что это утверд. конструкция, если у вас нет ссылок.

Comment: Ваша ссылка указывает на ответ от пользователей, словосочетание без контекста и поэтому речь о вас, что ссылка не подходит под данный вопрос, ведь данное сравнение не подходит, тк контекст имеется =ну и заголовок

Comment: Спасибо за беседу, но мы пошли по кругу)  Оставим без внимния все источники.  Докажите, что это утвердительная. конструкция. С моей точки зрения,  утверждение не имеет смысла: получается, что какое-то "ничего" непонятно.  А что же такое ничего, которое непонятно?

Comment: *А что же такое ничего* => Заголовок = в данном конкретном случае его **текст** (те то, из чего состоит собственно заголовок)

Comment: Не, не пойдет. Заголовок нельзя назвать словом "ничего".  Говорится: нельзя понять (не понятно)  ничего  в этом заголовке.

Comment: буквы, посыл, тема, связь предложения....те НИЧЕГО, нет чего-либо, чтоб понять автора и его заголовок https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otbqj.png

Comment: @Dev18, на будущее: "скриншот" — слитно)

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за внимание, я рассказала вам все, что могла.  Задайте свой вопрос на форуме.

Comment: @Dev18, пожалуй, вы правы. Извиняюсь.

Comment: https://uchi.ru/otvety/questions/kak-pishetsya-neponyatno-i-nedoslushal-slitno-ili-razdelno-s-ne?utm_referrer=https%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2f

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае Грамота права. Есть типа правило: раздельное написание означает отрицание, а слитное — утверждение противоположного. Ср.: *Он мне никакой **не друг** — я его первый раз вижу!* и *Он — мой **недруг**!*

А по теме здесь вообще-то правописание НЕ с наречиями на -о, если к наречию относятся слова, усиливающие отрицание: *далеко не, отнюдь не, ничуть не, нисколько не* и др.

Например:
*Задача решается далеко **не просто**. Он усмехнулся отнюдь **не весело**. Ты выглядел ничуть **не глупо**. Её слова звучали нисколько **не разумно**.*

https://gramota.ru/uchebnik/pravila/ne-s-narechiyami

Answer (score 2):

**Дополнение**

Об усилительном значении слова ***ничего***

1. Это слово **многозначное**, и поэтому важно определить, почему оно используется **для усиления отрицания.**

[Большой толковый словарь русского языка](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42)

**НИЧЕГО** [во]. **I. местоим. сущ. к Ничто.** II. **нареч. Разг.** (5 значений) **III. частица.** 1. Выражает одобрение, поддержку, допущение чего-л., оценку чего-л. как несущественного. Н., всё в порядке. Ну, давай, н., не бойся. Вы очень медленно всё делаете. - Н., зато хорошо. Н., не замёрзну, я бегом. Больно! - Н., до свадьбы заживёт. **2. Усиливает отрицание.** Н. она не похудела. Обиделся? - Н. я не обиделся. Это сложно? - Н. не сложно.

2. Итак, это не местоимение и не наречие, а частица. Сравним ***ничего*** с словом ***ничуть***, которое тоже используется для отрицания:

**НИЧУТЬ,** нареч. Разг. =Нисколько. Н. не холодно. Н. не опоздал. Не нравится н. Ты обиделся? - **Н. Н. не бывало (усилит.; вовсе нет).** * Уж не жду от жизни ничего я, И не жаль мне прошлого ничуть (Лермонтов). Ничуточки, нареч. Смягчит. **Мне н. не больно.** Ничуть не бывало, в зн. нареч. Не было ничего такого.

3. И можно сделать **вывод**, что слова **взаимозаменяемы** в усилительном значении: ***Ничего не*** понятно — это ***ничуть не*** понятно. Или ***нисколько не*** понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от контекста и стиля написания. Оба варианта возможны, но они могут нести немного разный смысл:

"Ну и заголовок, ничего непонятно..." (слитно) - в данном случае "ничего непонятно" является описанием состояния заголовка. Это можно интерпретировать как выражение недоумения или разочарования по поводу того, что заголовок не понятен или неясен.

"Ну и заголовок, ничего не понятно..." (раздельно) - в этом варианте "ничего не понятно" может быть воспринято как отдельное утверждение, что в заголовке действительно ничего не понятно, без прямой связи с фразой "Ну и заголовок".

Выбор между слитным и раздельным написанием может зависеть от того, какой смысл вы хотите передать и какой стиль предпочитаете использовать.

Comment: Ответ НЕКОРРЕКТНЫЙ.  Слово ничего содержит приставку НИ, которая усиливает ОТРИЦАНИЕ, но не утверждение.  Сравнить: абсолютно/совершенно непонятно. Это усиление утверждения. Классика орфографии, Розенталь, пункт 6  - 8.  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77  А если есть сомнения, то задайте вопрос на Грамоте.ру.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/16661/203473

Comment: @Sharon, ничего это заголовок, можем по третьему кругу если так уж прям. Ничего-ни буквы, ни связи, ни смысла, заголовок и есть НИЧЕГО

Comment: Пожалуйста,  уточните у Грамоты свою точку зрения, а потом мы обсудим их ответ. Пока же ваш ответ не соответствует правилу Розенталя и мнению большинства пользователей.

Comment: @Sharon, Ваши "заглавные буквы и количество рейтинга" вводит в заблуждения, того, кто будет искать ответ и увидит ваш комментарий. Так что делайте осторожней Ваши заключения

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую вам воздержаться от подобных замечаний, а обратиться за рекомендацией в Справочную службу. И тогда все будет ясно по поводу ЗАБЛУЖДЕНИЙ. Кстати, переход на личности на форуме запрещен (это я о рейтинге),

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнение**  => в сторону перевеса слитного написания

Обратите внимание на контекст, в котором использовано выражение "ничего непонятно". Если оно следует за утверждением о заголовке, то оно вероятно используется для описания состояния заголовка, а не для усиления отрицания.

Смысловая целостность: Выражение "ничего непонятно" в данном контексте имеет смысловую целостность, описывая отсутствие ясности или понимания, что соответствует употреблению в качестве утверждения.

"Ничего непонятно" - это употребление "ничего" в роли предикатива,
где оно выражает отрицательную оценку, подчеркивая непонимание.
В данном случае, "ничего" не употребляется с отрицательной частицей "не", но всё же передаёт отрицательный смысл.

"Вся эта история совершенно непонятна, ничего непонятно" - здесь "ничего непонятно"
также выражает непонимание и используется как предикатив, но в контексте общего недопонимания.

Эти примеры демонстрируют употребление "ничего непонятно" в роли предикатива,
где оно выражает отрицательную оценку, но не употребляется с отрицательной частицей "не".

поскольку, мы знаем откуда идет вопрос, рассмотрим на конкретном примере,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данной конструкции слово "непонятно" явно выражает отсутствие понимания, что указывает на утверждение о состоянии непонимания.

рассмотрим на аналогичных примерах использования подобной конструкции в литературе:

*стр.96 "Путники" Наталья Журавлёва*

...Она что-то пыталась нарисовать, но было **ничего непонятно**. К концу он всё же сумел разобрать, что говорит она ему о России...

*"Стекло и дерево" Сергей Буянов*

...Когда берешь в руки научный труд, не имея начальной базы знаний, текст представляет собой бессмысленный набор умных фраз. Особенно это выражено в технических науках, так как зачастую одна и та же буква обозначает различные величины, и откуда что появляется. А куда все уходит ? **Ничего непонятно**. Чувствуется : написано грамотно, умно, ничего не скажешь, но видать - не для среднего ума !

*глава 10 стр.64. Вопросы и ответы "Белый ворон" Владимир Афанасьевич Столяров*

-И все равно **ничего непонятно**! - Воскликнул Вико. - Что это было?! Кто они такие ...

*стр.46 Том 10 "Река и жизнь" Василий Песков*

...Я вижу все, что видит экипаж самолета. Но, увы, далеко не все понимаю, можно сказать **ничего непонятно**. Ну высота, скорость....

*Уильям Шекспир "12 ночь" (...больше мне ничего неизвестно...где неизвестно также пишется слитно)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти примеры демонстрируют, что такие конструкции вполне естественны для русского языка
и используются для выражения утверждений о непонимании или недовольства.

> И таким образом, делаем заключение, что
>
> **Ну и заголовок, ничего непонятно**
>
> дозволенннннннно писать **слитно !!!**

Comment: Дозволено пишется с одной Н, это причастие.  //Почему вы не задали вопрос на Грамоте.ру?  Скорее всего, опасаетесь, что решение будет не в вашу пользу.  К сожалению,  НИЧЕГО НЕ ПОНЯТНО  не воспринимается обычными пользователями на слух, это стало привычной ОШИБКОЙ. Вот такие ошибки нужно обсуждать с лингвистами на Грамоте.ру.  Если вдуматься в это сочетание, то оно совершенно бессмысленно.

Comment: Тема нашлась еще на другом ресурсе, там есть ссылка на Нацкорпус http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4360346-kak-pishetsja-sochetanie-nichego-ne-ponjatno.html#answer12367392

Answer (score 0):

```
  ВОПРОС №299997. Ничего непонятно или ничего не понятно – 
  как правильно писать, если дано только словосочетание, без 
  контекста? 
  ОТВЕТ. Верно: ничего не понятно.
```

***Ну и заголовок, ничего (не) понятно.***

Тема **активно просматривается** в Сети, поэтому я  уделю вопросу еще некоторое внимание.

Вроде бы все уже сказано, в том числе на сайте **Грамота.ру.** Поэтому сторонникам **слитного** написания предлагаю  выполнить **СИНТАКСИЧЕСКИЙ** разбор этого предложения **по всем правилам** для такого анализа: вид  предложения (простое, осложненное, сложное),  **[предикативная](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42&page=2)** основа, какие **частями речи** являются все слова. При разборе использовать **словари**, например толковый словарь Кузнецова.

```
  Эти примеры демонстрируют употребление "ничего непонятно" 
  в роли предикатива.
```

Нет, **не демонстрируют**, как бы этого ни хотелось. Предикативами в такой теме  являются наречия ***понятно*** и ***непонятно.*** К ним можно добавить усилительные слова: (1) абсолютно/совершенно непонятно, (2) нисколько/ничуть/совсем/ничего не понятно.

Эту **общеизвестную информацию** можно найти в справочнике Розенталя, в школьных учебниках и в учебниках по грамматике в теме "безличные предложения".  А вот для предикатива **"ничего непонятно"**  нужны ссылки на авторитетные **источники.** Хотелось бы такие ссылки **увидеть,** собственных рассуждений здесь **недостаточно.**

И уж,  казалось бы, чего проще как задать вопрос Справочной службе по поводу конкретного предложения: ***Ну и заголовок, ничего (не) понятно.*** Это если есть желание трактовать уже данный Грамотой ответ **по-своему.**

[Большой толковый словарь русского языка](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42&page=2)

НИЧЕГО. I. **местоим. сущ.** к Ничто. II. **нареч**. Разг. (5 значений) III. **частица**. 1. Выражает одобрение, поддержку, допущение чего-л., оценку чего-л. как несущественного. Н., всё в порядке. Ну, давай, н., не бойся. Вы очень медленно всё делаете. - Н., зато хорошо. Н., не замёрзну, я бегом. Больно! - Н., до свадьбы заживёт. 2. Усиливает отрицание. Н. она не похудела. Обиделся? - Н. я не обиделся. Это сложно? - Н. не сложно.